# How large (small) should a .NET assembly be?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, internal

Unfortunately, C# does not have anything like C++'s `friend`. Hence, for instance, in order to solve something like the classic matrix/vector multiplication example (where efficiency can be gained by befriending matrix and vector, such that each class has access to the private members of the other), I have to define the class members `internal`.

Now I know myself, and improper encapsulation will lead to messy code, sooner or later. Hence I would like to keep the `internal` universe as small as possible.

This will lead to very small assemblies.

Does that have any drawbacks, or doesn't that matter?

Comment: Are you assuming using the public interface is slow? I imagine you're accessing the ith and jth element via some property/indexer.  I thought the Microsoft JIT compiler was smart enough to inline trivial property accesses, so you're not buying yourself anything but code that breaks encapsulation.

Comment: As is always the answer for overly vague, poorly researched performance related questions... test.

Comment: Also, "Premature optimization is the root of all evil", right Ed? :)

Comment: It can never be to small =)

Comment: @Mario: True, no code runs faster than code which does not exist.

Comment: @Ed S.: Well, testing A does not necessarily mean that the answer will be true for B as well. Hence I do not consider it a stupid idea to ask about "best practice".

Comment: There is no B.  You are asking if you should *break* best practice because you have some unverified idea that there will be an unacceptable performance hit by using said best practices.  The answer is; test your code.  Is it performance?  Does it meet your requirements? If so, why are you worrying about it?

Comment: What's the problem with asking whether there is a rule of thumb on what should be gathered within one assembly and what shouldn't?

Comment: See the internalsvisibleto attribute. I think I first saw this technique from Jon Skeet. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx

Comment: An assembly is the smallest unit of independently versionable code. If two things cannot be sensibly versioned independently then don't put them in different assemblies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to question in the title: how small assembly should be?

There is no particular requirements or recommendations on size of assemblies*.

*Insane number of assemblies (probably in thousands) in theory may slow down loading due to need to lookup information in more places.

When picking size consider:

- proper encapsulation
- ease of editing (large number of solutions vs. several large one both have drawbacks and benifits at build/edit/deploy time)
- technical restrictions (like GAC deployment, partially trusted code, anyCPU/x86/x64 requirements)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like internal cause it's too open (to the rest of your api), make those classes that need to be open to eachother a separate microassembly containing just this small set of classes. You can always embed that assembly in your main api-assembly.

That should both keep your classes open to eachother, and not let anybody else in (unless they blatantly ignore your assembly-structure, and place more stuff in your helper-assembly than its name implies it should contain. But who would do such a thing?! :)

Answer (score 1):

Unless I don't understand:

> Unfortunately, C# does not have anything like C++'s friend.

[Friend Assemblies (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does exist.  It may not be exactly what C++ has, but it sounds like it would work.

Comment: Yes, but friend classes do not. And as I consider `internal` not restrictive enough, friend assemblies do not help.

Comment: What type of restriction do you need/have that requires a Class be private instead of internal in an assembly?